# Remove backwards slashes in string

Tags: php

When running a function which returns a string, I end up with backwards-slashes before a quotation marks, like this:

```
$string = get_string();
// returns: <a href=\"http://example.com/\">Example</a>
```

I suspect it is some type of escaping happening somewhere. I know I can string replace the backwards-slash, but I suppose in these cases, there is some type of unescape function you run?

Comment: Where is the string coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to escape quotes when it matches your starting/ending delimiter. This code should work properly:

```
$string = '<a href="http://example.com/">Example</a>';
```

If your string is enclosed in single quotes ', then " doesn't need to be escaped. Likewise, the opposite is true.

Avoid using `stripslashes()`, as it could cause issues if single quotes need to contain slashes. A simple find/replace should work for you:

```
$string = '<a href=\"http://example.com/\">Example</a>';
$string = str_replace($string, '\"', '"');
echo $string; //echos <a href="http://example.com/">Example</a>
```

Comment: When I echo the string, I see this in the HTML: `<a href=\"http://example.com/\">Example</a>` -- which completely breaks the HTML.

Comment: Did you modify the `$string` like my code block? The string should not contain any backslashes at all if you've copied my code.

Comment: No, sorry about the lack of clarification. I actually *get* the variable via a function which returns that string. So I don't *set* the variable myself.

Comment: You didn't put that in your original question. I'll update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

 $string = '<a href=\"http://example.com/\">Example</a>';

 echo stripslashes($string);

?>
```

Comment: As I've stated in my answer, `stripslashes()` will remove both backslashes before double quotes **and** single quotes. This may not be the intended behavior, as if a single quote needs to be escaped for javascript to function correctly, the html may break. `str_replace()` should be the correct solution.